# Java asks to create constructor that already exist

Tags: java, exception, constructor

I'm trying to create a client and server application in java. But I receive a `"The constructor ServerIO(Socket) is undefined"` exception. Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

My setup.server() function (simplified):

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import inputOutput.*;

public void server (int port) {
    try {
        ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket client = sock.accept();
        ServerIO serverIO = new ServerIO(client);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My input output handler constructor (simplified):

```
import java.net.Socket;

public ServerIO(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    try {
        this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        this.out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor ServerIO(Socket) is undefined

    at Setup.server(Setup.java:29)
    at Setup.main(Setup.java:113)
```

Comment: Yes I did. The ServerIO class is in the package inputOutput (see edit). The class ServerIO is the only class called this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the `Project -> Clean` option in Eclipse is to remove your already compiled files in order to build your project again from scratch.

It is likely you ran into a discrepancy between your code and the compiled file, with the compiled file not containing the constructor which was giving a confusing error.

I have found it useful to utilize this option when a confusing error happens, such as not finding something that clearly exists or an `import` seeming to not work. It is always a good idea to try to `Clean` to see if it fixes these issues, as it does not take very long to try it out either.